# JPA child entity versioning doesn't throw OptimisticLockException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities.
Foo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
public class Foo{
    ...
    @OneToOne(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_bar")
    private Bar bar;
    ...
}
```

Bar:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bar")
public class Bar{
    ...
    @Version
    private int version;
    ...
}
```

When I update Foo since I also made modification to Bar, it updates it and increments the version number which is correct. But it doesn't throw an OptimisticLockException if Bar was already update and so have a different version number. In the case I update Bar directly, it throws the exception. What can I do to make the exception throw when I update Bar through Foo ?

Concrete example:
It is a part of a web application. When I arrive on a page, I read Foo from the DB thanks to the method findById of a Dao. Since the relationship is one to one, I also get the Bar. Then I modify an attribute of Bar but I don't submit the form. I open the same web page, which will read the same Foo and Bar from the DB and then I modify an attribute of Bar and submit the form. In the DB I can see the new value of the attribute and the version incremented by one. Then I submit the form of my first we page which merge Foo and Bar. I don't get an optimistic lock but and if I look in the DB, I see that the attribute as the new value and the version is incremented by one. If instead of just merging foo, I merge Bar then Foo (and mark @JoinColumn(name = "id_bar", updatable = false)) doing the same manipulation as explained, I get an optimistic lock when I try to merge Bar the second times.

Comment: can you give a more concrete example of what you do when you expect but don't get the optimistic lock exception? Is the referenced Bar instance modified when you merge in your Foo instance? How have you read in the Foo and bar instances before merging them?

Comment: Hy @Chris I have added a concrete example as asked.

Comment: "which merge Foo and Bar" Devil is in the details and there are many ways to do that, and many tools to do that which will break optimistic locking like this. What exactly are you sending to your server, what does it do and what api methods specifically does it call. Ie do you build a java object from the JSON and use JPA merge api on it, and if so, what is the state of the entities before and after the merge call? I would suspect your client isn't sending the version field back and forth and the version value initially read isn't what is used or set on the entity to be merged.

Comment: Thank you @Chris your answer helped me to find the solution. When I build the java object from the JSON I still have the good version number but when I map this dto to the entity object, the version number wasn't correct